# Correct syntax use function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have read about syntax of function pointers and I can't make to work in my code.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axngwDJ79GY&ab_channel=JacobSorber) explains that the syntax is:

```
type func0(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn){
    // do something
    return a_thing;
}
```

Then for passing function pointers in another function is:

```
type func1((*func0)(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn), another args){  
    //do something
    func0(arg0, ..., argn);    
    return a_thing;
}
```

But then, I read the first answer about [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work), and the syntax is:

```
type func1((*func0)(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn), another args) {    
    //do something
    (*func0)(arg0, ..., argn);
    return a_thing;
}
```

which makes sense because you are dereferencing the pointer, which you are passing. Lastly, the first answer in [C function pointers invocation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622250/c-function-pointers-invocation-syntax) explain that the syntax can be:

```
&func
func
*func
**func
```

and I don't understand which info is correct. I have the code:

```
double *func1((*func0)(double), double *var) {
    double *temp = malloc(some_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < some_cycles; ++i) {
        temp[i] = (*func0)(var[i]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And it throws the error `a value of type "double *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double"`

EDIT:

For anyone wanted to see the real code, was that:

```
tensor_t *applyBinOpTensor(double *(operation)(double, double), tensor_t *tensor, double operand){

    size_t total_size = indiceProduct(*tensor->shape);
    double *values = malloc(total_size * sizeof(*values));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < total_size; ++i){
        values[i] = (*operation)(tensor->values[i], operand);
    }
    return initializeTensor(values, tensor->shape);
}
```

As you can see, all the problem was that I typed `double *(operation)(double, double)` instead of `double (*operation)(double, double)`.

Thanks to all for your answers. I learned a lot, and sorry for my misspeling.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: Wher is function return type? `And thorw the error` the code you  presented is missing `}}` and `#include <stdlib.h>`. Could you please post real full code example?

Comment: Please try to write syntactilly correct code. Your code has unmatched curly braces `{` in the wierdest places, so it is impossible to be sure what you mean. And please indent your code correctly.

Comment: I have this question that's kind of related. Might be worth a read too: [C++ Function call via an object with public member pointer to function, without using dereference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31869026/4561887). The function pointer call syntax is really interesting. See the bottom of my question.

Comment: @KamilCuk #include <stdlib.h> is in my code. I already posted the example in the question. It's the last onwe

Comment: @user694733 the code is indented correctly. Maybe it's your browser.

Comment: @DanielMuñoz `It's the last onwe` Yea, but `double *func1((*func0)(double), double *var)` doesn't compile. The `func0` is missing return type. It's `double *fund1(return_type (*func0)(double), double *var)`, where `return_type` can be `double` in this case. It looks like all your examples are missing the return type of the function pointers, which is kind of confusing. (Overall, the post has no clear questions, which for me makes it unclear, but I strongly sympathize with the confusion around function pointers. Anyway, C has 50 years, there are ton of resources online)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass a function pointer to a function is relatively easy.

Given some function pointer:

```
int (*fptr) (int, double);
```

Just squeeze the same syntax into the parameter list:

```
void some_func (int some_param, int (*fptr)(int, double), int some_other_param);
```

It turns more confusing when you try to return a function pointer. Lets take the above function and move the function pointer from the parameter list to the return type:

```
int (*some_func(int some_param, int some_other_param)) (int, double);
```

Yep, unreadable gibberish...

---

Now what can we actually learn from this?

- Whoever invented the function pointer syntax in C were confused.
- People who write code like the above are confused.
- People who try to learn function pointer syntax will get confused.
- If you have actually learnt the syntax, you have spent *way* too much time on nonsense, that could have been spent on better things.

**Always use typedef.** Period.

```c
typedef int func_t (int, double);

void some_func (int some_param, func_t* fptr, int some_other_param);

func_t* some_func (int some_param, int some_other_param);
```

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once I would. I learned to use a typedef fairly early on and so have never been able to read function pointer syntax. I regard that as time well not spent.

Comment: Upvoted. For function typedefs though, I prefer `typedef`ing to a function pointer, not a function, since functions automatically adjust to pointers anyway, and have no real "copy by value" concept I'm aware of. So I'd recommend this: `typedef int (*func_t)(int, double);`. Then, I'd use it in functions as `void some_func(func_t func);`, or `func_t some_func();`. And whether you do a call as `some_func(my_func);` or `some_func(&my_func);` makes no difference, since taking the address is optional due to the automatic adjustment of a function to a function pointer.

Comment: Very informative. Thanks. I'd accept this answer because its the more voted, but the other replies are also good.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Hiding a pointer behind a typedef is bad practice since it makes the code harder to read. Not doing so makes the function pointer syntax 100% equivalent with object pointer syntax. Particularly in terms of qualifiers. With a pointer hidden behind a typedef, `fptr const` is confusing and will trip most readers of your code. Whereas `fptr* const` is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 2):

They are best understood from a syntactical perspective. Say you have the functions `foo` and `bar`, sharing a common prototype:

```
int foo(float a, double b);
int bar(float c, double d);
```

Now we can declare a function pointer of type `int (*)(float, double)`:

```
int (*fptr)(float, double) = NULL;
```

Now, `fptr` can be assigned `foo` or `bar`:

```
fptr = foo;
...
fptr = bar;
fptr(2.0f, 3.0); /* indirect function call through the pointer */
(*fptr)(2.0f, 3.0); /* same */
```

For convenience, you can `typedef` that type to avoid having to type `int (*)(float, double)` all over the place:

```
typedef int (*fptr_t)(float, double);
```

After this, `fptr_t` will be a shorthand type for a function pointer with such a prototype.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I liked your typedef

Answer (score 1):

> But then, I read the firss answer about How do function pointers in C
> work?, and the syntax is:
>
> ```
> type func1((*func0)(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn), another args){
>
> //do something
> (*func0)(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn);
>
> return a_thing;
> }
> ```

No, syntax for function call via the function pointer is invalid. You want to pass something to it, not de declare function pointer again. Also you miss the return type of the function in function pointer parameters declaration

```
 type func1(type1 (*func0)(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn), another args){

 func0(par1, ..., parn);
```

you can also use this form

```
 (*func0)(par1, ..., parn);
```

as they equivalent.

> and I dont understand which info is correct. I have the code:
>
> ```
> double *func1((*func0)(double), double *var){
>     double *temp = malloc(some_size);
>
>     for(int i = 0; i < some_cycles; ++i){    
>          temp[i] = (*func)(var[i]);
>
>     return temp;
> ```

Your function pointer parameter is called `func0` and you use `func`. Also the function parameter declaration is invalid as it requires the return value too. The correct function definition:

```
#define some_cycles 10

double *func1(double (*func0)(double), double *var)
{
    double *temp = malloc(some_cycles * sizeof(*temp));

    for(int i = 0; i < some_cycles; ++i){
        temp[i] = func0(var[i]);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How to make the question code executable

I have tested your code and made some changes to it so that it can be executed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int some_cycles = 10;

//*********************************************************
// I HAVE ADDED THIS FUNCTION TO PASS IT AS FIRST ARGUMENT
// OF YOUR FUNCTION func1
//*********************************************************
double f(double d) {
    d++;
    return d;
}

//*********************************************************
// THIS IS YOUR FUNCTION
//*********************************************************
double *func1(double (*func0)(double), double *var){
    double *temp = malloc(some_cycles * sizeof(double));

    for(int i = 0; i < some_cycles; ++i){
        temp[i] = (*func0)(var[i]);
    }

    // I HAVE ADDED THE FOLLOWING for loop WITH printf() TO THE BODY
    // OF YOUR FUNCTION TO SHOW THE CONTENT OF THE LOCAL ARRAY temp
    for(int i = 0; i < some_cycles; ++i){
        printf("%f\n", temp[i]);
    }

    return temp;
}


//*********************************************************
// THIS IS THE MAIN FUNCTION
//*********************************************************
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    double var[] = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0};
    func1(f, var);
    return 0;
}
```

#### The output of the code execution

If you compile and execute the previous code the output is:

```
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
7.000000
8.000000
9.000000
10.000000
```

#### Errors in the question code

I would like to highlight two errors in your code:

**1.** you have to use `func0` in the body of your `for` loop (and not `func` which is not declared anywhere)

**2.** you missed the type `double` in the definition of the first argument of the function `func1`; so you have to use:

```
double (*func0)(double)
```

and not:

```
(*func0)(double)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then for passing function pointers in another function is:
>
> …
> `func0(type0 arg0, ..., typen argn);`

No, to call a function, you use only the arguments, not the types:

`func0(arg0, ..., argn);`

> Lastly, the first answer in [C function pointers invocation syntax][3] explain that the syntax can be:
>
> `&func`
> `func`
> `*func`
> `**func`

Any of these will work. The specified operand for a function call is a pointer to a function, so `&func(arguments)` is the “most direct” way to use the function call operator, `(…)`. However, functions are automatically converted to pointers to functions. So `func(arguments)` works because it is automatically converted to `&func(arguments)`.

The rule is that whenever a function is used in an expression other than has the operand of `sizeof` (which causes an error) or as the operand of unary `&`, it is converted to a pointer to the function (C 2018 6.3.2.1 4). This is also why you can use `*func` and `**func`. In `(*func)(arguments)`, `func` is not the operand of `sizeof` or `&`, so it is converted to a pointer to the function. Then `*` takes the pointer and produces what it references, which is the function. Then this function is also not the operand of `sizeof` or `&`, so it is also converted to a pointer to the function. The result is as if the code were `<code>&func(<i>arguments</i>)</code>`, which is correct for a function call.

Similarly, in `(**func)(arguments)`, this automatic conversion occurs three times. No matter how many times you apply `*`, the result will be automatically converted back to a pointer to the function.

> I have the code:
>
> `double *func1((*func0)(double), double *var){`
>
> `double *temp = malloc(some_size);`
>
> `for(int i = 0; i < some_cycles; ++i){`
> `temp[i] = (*func)(var[i]);`

You have some mistake in posting this code, because there is no `func` declared before `(*func)(var[i])`, and there is a missing `}`. The error message you are getting looks like attempting to use some function declared to return `double *`, which `func1` is declared to return. You will need to fix up the code in the question before the error can be explained.